# Is it possible to make elasticsearch index a SVN repo? And specific branches?

Tags: svn, indexing, elasticsearch

Is it possible to make Elasticsearch index a SVN repo directly? and all Docs, and PDFs within it?

Comment: It's not clear - what `directly` part means exactly? Do you want to write no code and seekeing for out-of-box solution? Or you have remote repo and want to access it directly? Something else? Could you please explain?

Comment: Sure. I meant without any interfaces. ElasticSearch <-> SVN, no middle man.

Comment: Then you can create your own elasticsearch river that will be sitting there and indexing your repo using library like svnkit.

Comment: Rivers will be deprecated from what I heard...